# Upload a CSV file through a JSP page and print its contents using a Servlet..?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to design a JSP page through which user uploads a CSV file and then I need to print its contents on the screen through a Servlet.

The HTML code goes likes this

```
<form action="decode" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post>
    <input type="file" name="record" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now In decode.java,

```
DiskFileItemFactory fi = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletContext sc = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
File file = (File) sc.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
fi.setRepository(file);
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(fi);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

What should I do next to read each and every word from the uploaded CSV file...?
I do not want to store the CSV file anywhere. Just want to read its contents and print them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read CSV files using Apache's CSV parser library for JAVA.

And then after importing the library in your classpath you can simply use it as

```
Reader in = new FileReader(file); //The file is the file which you get from the request(java.io.File)
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    //Do something with the records
}
```

For more information look into https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html

Comment: Can you tell me about what should I write next...? i.e.
Reader in = //...?

Comment: using the same file object as in my question, doesn't solve my question... what all do I need to change...?

Comment: What problem you are facing, can you show me the trace? can you give me more details about it as I am not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Yes that means the file you get from the server as request is not valid. As soon as the file you get as a request from server is valid, everything else will start working, File file = (File) sc.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
I am not sure how you save the file or keep the file as you need to open the file and then pass it to the Reader.

Comment: Also according to your question all you wanted to know was how to read the content of CSV file.

Comment: After a bit of debugging, I found out that the FileReader needs the exact path for the CSV for e.g. ("/path/myfile.csv") whereas, the 'file' object only has the path of the directory and not the file itself. That's where it is failing.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if your problem was solved. If not can you let me know what is not working.

Comment: Done... Some other things are bugging now but yeah, you gave the correct answer to solve my problem. thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar requirement, where I need to upload a jsp file through jsp and process it through Servlet

So Here I used the Library called opencsv by Apache.

> upload.jsp

```
<form action="./upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="description" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

> UploadServlet.java

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;


@WebServlet(name = "upload", urlPatterns = { "/upload" })
@MultipartConfig
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public UploadServlet() {
        super();
    }

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); 
        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(fileContent);

        CSVReader reader;
        Iterator<String[]> iterator;

        try {

            reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(fileContent));
            iterator = reader.iterator();

            String[] row = iterator.next();

            Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
                map.put(i, row[i]);

                //Do rest of the code

            }

        }catch(Exception e) {}

        in.close();

    }

}
```

> **Additional** :

While developing the above requirement I also encountered a problem, where a exception is throw specifying ClassNotFound.... (When converting inputstream to CSVReader instance)

It's because the library is not attached to Runtime environment even though it's properly attached to Development environment.

**Solution :**

Copy the library files to lib folder in the server location and restart the server (shutdown first then start).
By doing this I was able to solve the issue

Another better option is to use some Build tool like gradle or maven rather than going with JSP/Servlet(my personal view)